# Não consigo carregar o CSS, JavaScript e imagens na minha página com Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, api

ao executar o `index.html` não funciona css, javascript e nem imagens.

Meu código está assim :

```
const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign'); //importando a biblioteca
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = () => {
    const app = express();//Exetando o express 


    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/imagens'))
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

    consign() //aqui, tudo que tiver no modulo controle vai passar para o app, para ele começar a executar o que tem lá 
        .include("controles")
        .into(app)

    return app
}







const configExpress = require("./configServidor/configExpress");
const conexao = require("./infraestrutura/conexao");
const tabelas = require("./infraestrutura/tabelas");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");


conexao.connect(function(erro){//conectando banco de dados
    if(erro){
        console.log(erro)
    }else{

        console.log("conectado com sucesso!");
        tabelas.init(conexao);


        http.createServer((req,res) => {
            const app = configExpress();

            fs.readFile(
                path.join(__dirname,"campeonatos.html"),(erro,content) =>{
                    if(erro) throw erro;
    
                    res.end(content);
                }
            )
        }).listen(3000, () => console.log("Servidor rodando na porta 3000.")); //Subindo o servidor
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a rota usada no `app.use` (`/css`, `/js`, `/imagens`) antes do `express.static`

```
const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign'); //importando a biblioteca
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = () => {
    const app = express();//Exetando o express 

    //       ↓↓↓↓ - Tente isso
    app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'))
    app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'))
    app.use('/imagens', express.static(__dirname + '/imagens'))
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

    consign() //aqui, tudo que tiver no modulo controle vai passar para o app, para ele começar a executar o que tem lá 
        .include("controles")
        .into(app)

    return app
}







const configExpress = require("./configServidor/configExpress");
const conexao = require("./infraestrutura/conexao");
const tabelas = require("./infraestrutura/tabelas");
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
```